# How do I check if SELECT statement returns no rows in C with SQLITE?

Tags: c, sqlite, null

I want to create a registration function and I want to verify if a user name is already in my database. I do not know how to verify if "SELECT" statement returns NULL. This is what i wrote so far:

```
strcat(msg, "Insert username:\n");

if(write(client, msg, 100) <= 0)
{
perror("Error");
exit(1);
}

if(read(client, name, 30) <= 0)
{
perror("Error");
exit(1);
}
sqlite3_stmt *res;
char sql[100];

sprintf("SELECT * FROM users where name=\"%s\";", name);

int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, NULL);

if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
perror("Error");
exit(1);
}

int step = sqlite3_step(res);
if(step != SQLITE_DONE)
{
perror("Error");
exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html):

> SQLITE_DONE means that the statement has finished executing successfully. sqlite3_step() should not be called again on this virtual machine without first calling sqlite3_reset() to reset the virtual machine back to its initial state.
>
> If the SQL statement being executed returns any data, then SQLITE_ROW is returned each time a new row of data is ready for processing by the caller. The values may be accessed using the column access functions. sqlite3_step() is called again to retrieve the next row of data.

I will admit that this isn't very obvious, but what this actually means for empty result sets is that `sqlite3_step` will return `SQLITE_DONE` right off the bet, not `SQLITE_ROW`. I've not used sqlite in C before, but that's how I understood the docs, but I think I'm right, especially after checking the sqlite forum [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/sqlite3-step-behavior-on-empty-set-td57514.html)

```
> Is my impression correct that when calling sqlite3_step() on a query 
> that returns no rows, the result will be [SQLITE_DONE]? 

Yes. 

> If that is the case, might that be added to the documentation? 

"SQLITE_DONE means that the statement has finished executing successfully." 
"If the SQL statement being executed returns any data, then SQLITE_ROW is returned each time a new row of data is ready for processing by the caller." 

The implication is that if SQL statement doesn't return any data, then sqlite3_step doesn't return SQLITE_ROW. Since it nevertheless finishes executing successfully, it returns SQLITE_DONE. 
-- 
Igor Tandetnik
```

Based on this info, the last bit of your code seems wrong to me:

```
int step = sqlite3_step(res);
if(step != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
}
```

If `step != SQLITE_DONE`, it might be `SQLITE_ROW`, which isn't an error, it just means the query returned a result, and you should set about processing that data. If you want to treat empty result sets as an error, then you might change it to this:

```
int step = sqlite3_step(res);
if(step != SQLITE_ROW)
{
    if (step == SQLITE_DONE)
        perror("No results");
    else
        perror("Error");
    exit(1);
}
```